# Coordinates of mouse events in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, mousedown

I would like to create a mouse event manually on an point, knowing its coordinates. I use this function :

```
$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).mousedown();
```

The click is used by a function that needs the `pageX` and `pageY` properties of the event, but it does not work because the created event doesn't have these properties.
Does anybody know why?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't have the x/y values, what are they supposed to be?

Comment: They are supposed to be the same as those I use in my function elementFromPoint, but I can't give them directly to the other function. In fact, the mousedown event is fired when an dragged element is dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a jQuery event with the required properties an pass it over to the "trigger function":

```
var event = jQuery.Event("mousedown", {pageX: x, pageY: y});
$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).trigger(event);
```

That should work.